# Changing boolean value with "wp option patch"

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to change a boolean value (in a serialized object) via `wp option patch`. But it doesn't work. If I use `true` (without quotes), it changes to string, if I use `1`, it changes to int. Is there a way anyone knows of?

Here is the part of the serialized object before:

`s:18:"/contact-form-7/v1";b:0`

`wp option patch insert disable_rest_api_options roles none allow_list '/contact-form-7/v1' 1`

changes it to

`s:18:"/contact-form-7/v1";i:1`

`wp option patch insert disable_rest_api_options roles none allow_list '/contact-form-7/v1' true`

changes it to

`s:18:"/contact-form-7/v1";s:4:"true"`

I want it to be

`s:18:"/contact-form-7/v1";b:1`

Chris

Comment: Might help if you showed your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution. One has to use the json-format.

`wp option patch insert disable_rest_api_options roles none allow_list '/contact-form-7/v1' true --format=json`

gives the desired object:

`s:18:"/contact-form-7/v1";b:1`